# What is the affect of the value given to an axis in rotation3DEffect (besides just rotating around said axis)

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, 3d

So I know I can do for example:

```
var body: some View {
    someView
        .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: 45), axis: (1, 0, 0))
}
```

And this will rotate `someView` 45 degrees on the `x` axis.

*My Question*

What does the actual value (in this case 1.0) represent? What would happen if it was 0.5? How does this affect other axis.

> Note: Something does happen if more than one axis are set, a la `(10, -2, 0)`

I can't find anything that doesn't just show an example of code and none have clarified what affect the actual value has.

Here, 1.0 (I see most tutorials say 1.0). If I change the values around with more than 1 axis, I see that *something* is happening.

Comment: Didn't you just check the documentation? I am SURE it is explained in there...  ;) Sorry, it is Friday afternoon... I have noticed that as the numbers get larger, the effect is less pronounced...

Comment: @Yrb - it's definitely not, if you have any other spots, I'd love to look! I checked everywhere, I might not know the right search terms, but the function docs and manual don't say much

Comment: Agreed, which is pretty typical of the documentation from Apple. I was hoping the dripping sarcasm in my comment was more clear. This may be one of those things where you make a test app with sliders and see what happens.

Comment: The word 'affect' is a verb, not a noun.

Comment: The 3D axis must be a unit vector. (1,0,0) is unit vector i.e., the norm is equal to 1. If you use a non-unit vector like (10,-2,0) then you are applying a scaling as well as rotation. The scale factor would be the norm of the vector, like sqrt(10^2 + (-2)^2) ~ 10.198

Comment: To me they represent weights `(1, 0, 0)` has the same effect as `(100, 0, 0)`, and `(0.5, 0, 0)`. Whereas `(2, 1, 0)` has the same effect as `(1, 0.5, 0)`. `0` just represent no weight.

Comment: you can also think of them as percentages too: `(10, -2, 0)` would mean `10 / 12` % in first axis, `2/ 12` % (in the negative direction) in the second axis and 0 percent in the third axis. which is 83.33%, -16.66% and 0%. You can enter `(0.83, -0.17, 0)` and it will result in the same rotation. Note: the `12` is `10 + 2 + 0`